# Don't know how to realize some issues in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My application has a Rating model and a Party model which belongs_to Rating.

When I create a new Rating, Rails renders a form to take the Rating name and than creates it, with no parties.

But I want Rating to have **at least two parties**, so when I create a new Rating, after submitting the name it should redirect to creating 2 parties.

Do not sure how to realize that, do you have some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you probably want [Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) with [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) for the form. This will enable you to easily create your `Party` objects from your `Rating` controller.

Comment: ok, created the form I needed, and it works, but as I added delete button to each nested form, don't know how to add validation that Rating has at least two patries... Should it be in model or in controller?

Comment: Most people would probably suggest you should do that in the model, either that or the view (JS). If you're going to do it in the model, think about a [before_save](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback.

Comment: However if you're adding and removing the Parties with JS, use JS to ensure you don't have less than two.

Comment: Thanks! I think a would do it through Js as it ajax based